# how to add a image uploader in magento 2 checkout shipping address section?

Tags: onepage-checkout, custom, magento2.3.3

I have a custom requirement to upload **customer id** during checkout.

I have created a custom module with a text type input file. data saved and everything fine the process was.

I want to update the text type to file uploading type.

i tried below method in my custom module. But i am getting an error.

***Created a phtml file in***

***/view/fronted/web/template/form/element/newtempfile.phtml***

```
<input class="input-file" type="file" data-bind="value: value,
valueUpdate: 'keyup',hasFocus: focused,attr: {
name: inputName,
placeholder: placeholder,
'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
'aria-required': required,
'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
id: uid,
disabled: disabled }" />
```

***And defined in the plugin file like below***

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\CheckoutCustomField\Plugin;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;
class SmsPlugin
{
public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout) {
    $customAttributeCode = 'sms';
    $customField = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'customEntry' => null,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'Ayakil_CheckoutCustomField/form/element/newtempfile',
            'tooltip' => [
                'description' => 'Mobile (Courier text notifications)',
            ],
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
        'label' => 'Custom SMS Attribute',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 0,
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => true
        ],
        'options' => [],
        'filterBy' => null,
        'customEntry' => null,
        'visible' => true,
    ];

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

    return $jsLayout;
}
}
```

But i am getting an error.

```
 [2020-01-27 01:12:57] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Ayakil_CheckoutCustomField/form/element/newtempfile" template requested by "checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.sms".
```

How to upload and save an image in magento 2 checout in shipping form section.Please help me to solve this task.

Comment: `newtempfile.phtml` should be an html file and not phtml

Comment: @Piyush thank you very much, Any idea to handle the upload file and processed in the order section to see by admin ?

Comment: are you managed to get this working? @Mujahidh

Answer (score -1):

In Magento Marketplace there are some extensions are available to order attachment. it will be helpful for you. please check the below extension
https://marketplace.magento.com/meetanshi-magento2-order-attachment.html (paid)
https://marketplace.magento.com/sp-orderattachment.html (free)